# Get a list of SNS topics for an AWS account, with Publish permissions

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Is there a way to find a list of SNS topics where a given AWS Account ID has PUBLISH (or any other) permissions?

My use case is as follows:

1. A server program allows different clients to post messages onto an SNS topic that it owns. The server program has these SNS topics in various AWS regions.
2. Each client is granted “Publish” permission on the SNS topic, in each AWS region.
3. The client is given the name of the topic and based on the region, it has to derive the topic ARN and publish messages.

I would like to avoid maintaining the ARNs of these topics, by AWS region and distribute them in a client config and was wondering if there is a way for the clients to derive the Topic ARN based on the Topic Name and the AWS Region, through some API provided by AWS (and not form the ARN as `aws:${region}:sns:${topicName}`.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming ListTopicsResult will only return topic arns of topics you can access.

```java
import java.util.List;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.ListTopicsRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.ListTopicsResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.Topic;

public class TestSNS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(args[0], args[1]);
        AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(credentials);

        ListTopicsResult listTopicsResult = snsClient.listTopics();
        String nextToken = listTopicsResult.getNextToken();
        List<Topic> topics = listTopicsResult.getTopics();

        // ListTopicResult contains only 100 topics hence use next token to get
        // next 100 topics.
        while (nextToken != null) {
            listTopicsResult = snsClient.listTopics(nextToken);
            nextToken = listTopicsResult.getNextToken();
            topics.addAll(listTopicsResult.getTopics());
        }

        // Display all the Topic ARN's
        for (Topic topic : topics) {
            System.out.println(topic);
            /*
             * perform your actions here
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but It is worth mentioning to other visitors that the above code has a bug. One must use the `nextToken` when calling to `snsClient.listTopics()` otherwise you will have an infinite loop (provided you have more than 100 topics).

Comment: why will there be an infinite loop, if calling snsClient.listTopics() returns a maximum of 100 topics ?

Comment: because the `nextToken` is not passed to the subsequent `listTopics()` calls. Thus everytime that loop iterates, it will only ever list the first 100 topics (and have a nextToken present). The call within the while loop should be `listTopicsResult = snsClient.listTopics(nextToken);`